# Are заслуживать + acc and заслуживать + gen synonymous?

Tags: падежи

The Russian National Corpus gives numerous examples of both заслуживать внимание and заслуживать внимания (without negation). Is this an instance when either case can be used with this verb? I understand that one means more or less "deserves" or "earn" while the other means more or less "is worthy of".

Comment: Please disregard my (deleted) answer. My parallels with the indefinite/definite marking of the negative genitive/accusative weren't very well thought through. Shouldn't do this while tired.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the two are definitely not synonymous.

> -- Почему он так внимательно слушает эту женщину?
> -- Мне кажется, он заслуживает её внимани**е**. (He is earning [seeking] her attention)
>
> -- Почему эта женщина так внимательно его слушает?
> -- Мне кажется, он заслуживает её внимани**я**. (He deserves [is worthy of] her attention)

So there is *заслуживать* = *зарабатывать* and there is *заслуживать* = *быть достойным*.

Answer (score 2):

Avi Gordon is correct saying that the verb заслуживать can be translated as to seek as well as to deserve, but in the phrase

> Он заслуживает внимания.

there is the Genitive partitive, i.e. he deserves (some, not all) attention.